# html - how can I use row striping with anchors for these unordered lists?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to make a layout with rows that will be dragged.

[image]

I can strip the table nicely (table on right with green border) but when I add anchor tags so that these become big draggable cells (they're going to be dragged), the striping goes away and they have a gray background (table on left with yellow border).

HTML/CSS:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    #categorizer { padding: 20px; }
    #left  {
      color: green;
      background-color: yellow;
      display: inline;
      border: solid;
      border-color: pink, 10px
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 20px;
    }   
    #right {
      color: yellow;
      background-color: green;
      display: inline;
      border: solid;
      border-color: pink, 10px
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 20px;
    }   
    ul  
    {   
      padding: 30px;
      margin: 30px;
      float:left;
      list-style:none;
    }   
    li {
    padding: 20px;
    }   
    li:nth-child(even) { background-color: #000 }
    li:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #666 }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="categorizer">
      <ul id="left">
        <a href="#"><li>1</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>2</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>3</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>4</li></a>
      </ul>
      <ul id="right">
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
        <li>d</li>
        <li>e</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I have big draggable cells that 'show the hand' - not just over the letters, but the whole cell - that's important - but still apply the table striping (could also be 20+ rows for this, that's dynamic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

move all your `<a>` tags in your `<li>`
and add to your css `cursor:move` to `li` to add a hand to each `li` elements.

[jsLint Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Class/MRSct/)

HTML:

```
<li><a href="#">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">4</a></li>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    cursor:move;
}
```

you might want to change `li{` to `li, li > a` in your css to have your `a` tags don't show the pointer, unless you want that.

Comment: When I want to do the dragging do I then look at the li.  If so, and using your `cursor:move` technique, can I remove the <a> tags as they are not really hyperlinks but draggable elements.

Comment: if you are using something like jquery you can remove the a tags and in jquery have something like `$('#left li').each(function(){...});`

Comment: I tried it and it works visually at least - i get striping and the hand.  Haven't added the real dragging yet.

Comment: Or you can use [jquery ui draging w/sorting](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable) or unless you have something else you have in plan for dragging implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have an `<a>` as a direct child of a `<ul>` or `<ol>` only a `<li>` is valid - simply switch the order around for your first list (`#left`) and set the `<a>` to `display: block;`

```
<ul id="left">
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
 </ul>
```